# Flex items not wrapping

Tags: html, css, flexbox

My issue is that I have a `section` within the `article` that I made a flexbox, and when I reduce the size of the browser those 3 elements in that flexbox will overlap. Any tips?

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
header {
  background: blue;
}
main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: auto;
}
article {
  flex: 2;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: red;
}
aside {
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: green;
}
.test {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: auto;
  align-items: stretch;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    Test
  </header>
  <main>
    <article>
      <section>
        test
      </section>
      <section class="test">
        <div>
          div one
        </div>
        div two
        <div>
          div three
        </div>
        <div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </article>
    <aside>
      aside
    </aside>
  </main>
  <footer>
  </footer>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zLmcyjy6/

Comment: Try adding `flex-wrap: wrap` to the flex container. Flex items do not wrap by default.

Comment: Doesn't seem to fix the problem, the images in the link I provided overlap when you minimize the browser and flex wrap doesn't push it to it's own line for some reason, I hard defined the size of those images though, could that be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `flex-wrap: wrap` to the flex container. Flex items do not wrap by default.

---

In reference to [your website](http://173.246.106.179/) (I didn't use your [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zLmcyjy6/), which has different code), each of the non-wrapping elements is a `<section>` child of `<section class="other">`, which is a row-direction, wrap-enabled flex container.

Each `<section>` flex item has a `flex: 1` applied. This translates to:

- `flex-grow: 1`
- `flex-shrink: 1`
- `flex-basis: 0`

With `flex-basis` set to zero, the initial main size of the flex item is 0, and the width could shrink to that degree, so there's no opportunity to wrap.

I would suggest changing `flex-basis: 0` to something like `flex-basis: calc(33% - 2em)` (i.e., width minus approx. margin, border, padding), for wider screens. So `flex: 1 1 calc(33% - 2em)`.

And then for smaller screens, using a media query, set `flex-basis` to something like:

```
@media screen and ( max-width: 500px ) {
    .fitness, .education, .pastimes {
        flex-basis: 100%;
        display: flex; /* optional; for nicer alignment */
        flex-direction: column;  /* optional; for nicer alignment */ }
    }
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to avoid using media queries, you could set a fixed value to `flex-basis` which would enable wrap, as well. Something like `flex: 1 0 200px`.